# sort -R using specific key instead of entire line.

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a file in the format:

```
key1    1    <value>
key1    2    <value>
key1    3    <value>
key2    1    <value>
key2    2    <value>
key3    1    <value>
key3    2    <value>
```

I would like to shuffle this file by the key, but I would like the ordering of the blocks with the same key to stay the same. So an acceptable ordering would be:

```
key3    1    <value>
key3    2    <value>
key2    1    <value>
key2    2    <value>
key1    1    <value>
key1    2    <value>
key1    3    <value>
```

Is there any way to do this with `sort -R`?

Comment: Max, did you try `sort -k` ?  check out the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)

Comment: Does this work with -R as well?

Comment: yes, `-k` should work with `-R`. Depending on the version of sort you're running you may also have `--debug` which you may want to append as it will annotate the parts that were used to sort

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly the data in the file or exactly how you want it sorted, it will be hard to give the exact answer for which you seek. Sort has many "gotchas" that aren't always intuitive, remember to visit the man page every now and then. However, here are examples that may help:

```sh
sort -R -k1,1 -k2,2n -b -s
```

1. Sort by random has of keys, Sort column 2 by numeric--overwrite the random for this key, Ignore leading blanks, and disable last-resort comparison

```sh
sort -k1,1R -k2,2n
```

2. Sort column 1 by random has of keys, Sort column 2 by numeric

```sh
sort -k1,1R -k2,2rn
```

3. Sort column 1 by random has of keys, revesre-sort column 2 by numeric